# How to validate ssh keys in AWX running in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, freeipa, ansible-tower

**Background**

We use Ansible/AWX running in Kubernetes (awx-operator) to manage workstations with dynamic hostnames. Authentication is handled by Red Hat IDM (FreeIPA) and the same credentials are used to log in to each workstation.

**The problem**

Hostnames don't always update immediately, and sometimes Ansible connects to a host the wrong host (e.g. DNS for `test1.domain.local` -> `172.1.1.10`, which actually now belongs to `test2.domain.local`). Because the credentials still work to log in to `test2.domain.local`, ansible doesn't know it's connected to the wrong host and proceeds on its merry way, wreaking all sorts of havoc.

**Workaround/attempted solutions**

*Note: I do plan to address the underlying issue of changing hostnames (e.g. DHCP reservations or static IPs), but I would also like to solve the problem of ansible happily connecting to the wrong host, and I would think there would be an easy solution out there.*

I've implemented a workaround using a static `known_hosts` file (generated from IDM using `sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy`) and passed through to the EE using a volume mount. This works, but it's not great as there is no way to dynamically update it as hosts are added/removed/rebuilt in IDM.

Ideally I would just use `sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy` from inside the EE (`ProxyCommand` in `ssh_config`, just like on the host), but this appears to rely on the host being joined to the IDM itself (I'm not really sure here, but running `sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy` from inside the container does not work).

I also tried a Kerberos principal in IDM and keytab in the container, but this appears to open a whole other can of worms with required files from the host, and the dynamic nature of the container's hostname. Not to mention I have no idea if simply having a valid kerberos token would resolve the issue, or if there's another can of worms following this one.

**Questions**

1. Do others validate host keys when connecting with ansible? There does not appear to be a lot of documentation on *enabling* `StrictHostKeyChecking` in ansible — everything I see advises disabling it, but I would think this would be bad practice.
2. How do others handle service auth inside k8s? I'm a Kubernetes newbie so any best practices would be helpful.
3. How does `sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy` work? What files/configuration specifically does it rely on?
4. How would you handle my issue? Am I on the right track with `StrictHostKeyChecking` and `sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy` or am I missing something else obvious?